# Open help windows in new buffer instead of split windows

Tags: vim-windows, help-system

Some time ago I found an interesting trick on [Damian Conway's vimrc](https://github.com/thoughtstream/Damian-Conway-s-Vim-Setup/blob/master/.vimrc#L875-887) 
which allows to open help files in new tabs instead of split windows. 
The code is the following:

```
"Only apply to .txt files...
augroup HelpInTabs
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufEnter  *.txt   call HelpInNewTab()
augroup END

"Only apply to help files...
function! HelpInNewTab ()
    if &buftype == 'help' && g:help_in_tabs
        "Convert the help window to a tab...
        execute "normal \<C-W>T"
    endif
endfunction
```

Of course this piece of code works well but I'd like to improve it: I feel that opening the 
help file into a new tab isn't that convenient and I rather open it into a new buffer and
give the focus on this buffer.

So I'm looking for a command which would replace this line:

```
execute "normal \<C-W>T"
```

and more precisely `<C-W>T` to turn the window into a new buffer instead of a new tab.

Unfortunately, I could find anything which could help me in the documentation. So is it possible?
And if it is, how can I do it?

Comment: I think you want `<C-w>o`? (also see: [How to “full screen” browse Vim help?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/358/51)).

Comment: Erf how could have I not find this? (Maybe this question should be marked as duplicate actually) That's exactly what I want thanks. But is it normal that when I'm on an help buffer, I do `:bn` to go back to my previous buffer that close the help buffer (it doesn't appear anymore in `:ls`)?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: I just accepted Peter's answer, but could you make your solution an answer? It is what I was looking for on the beginning and it solve my problem so I think that is worth an answer :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can open help in the current window by `set buftype=help` and then using the `:help` command.

We have the following problems:

- restore the `'buftype'` value of the previous buffer, `#`, in the success case
- restore the `'buftype'` value of the current buffer, `%`, in the error case
- let the `:h` error message through correctly

The `:h` command like so many of Vim's command will set `v:errmsg` when an error messages occurs. This means we can detect the error message. However this will give a "stack trace" when used inside of a function. We can overcome this by suppressing the error via `:silent!`. Now we can check `v:errmsg` and restore `'buftype'` correctly.

Since you still want to keep the error message we will use `:execute` in the `:command` definition and have the function return the failed help command.

Below is the resulting code (Put this in your `vimrc` file):

```
function! s:help(subject)
  let buftype = &buftype
  let &buftype = 'help'
  let v:errmsg = ''
  let cmd = "help " . a:subject
  silent! execute  cmd
  if v:errmsg != ''
    let &buftype = buftype
    return cmd
  else
    call setbufvar('#', '&buftype', buftype)
  endif
endfunction
command! -nargs=? -bar -complete=help H execute <SID>help(<q-args>)
```

This creates the `:H` command which behave just like `:h` except open in the same window.

#### Thoughts

- You may want to look into something like [cmdallias.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=746) to make this command easier to type
- Maybe instead of all this trouble just promote the help window to its own tab via `<c-w>T` (my preference)
- the technique will need to be adjusted to take into consideration if there is a different a window with `buftype=help` already open

#### More help

```
:h 'buftype'
:h :h
:h :silent
:h v:errmsg
:h :exe
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sorry for my late comment! First: your method seems to be more reliable than mine combined with the comment of CarpetSmoker (using `<C-w>o`) but I haven't tested it yet in full depth. Secondly I have a question: with you method just like with mine, the help buffer seems to disapear (just like I described it in the comment on my question), is it an expected behavior? And if so is it possible to get rid of it so I can open an help buffer and then switch between it and my others buffers?

Comment: Help buffers are unlisted so they do not show up in `:ls` or navigable via simple `:bn`/`:bp` commands. To see unlisted buffers do `:ls!`. Now if you use `<c-^>`/`<c-6>` you can easily switch between the current buffer and the alternative buffer. I remap this command to backspace via `nnoremap <bs> <c-^>` to make switching easier. If you really want to switch between the buffers you can do `set buflisted` around line 7 of the function, but that will clutter up your buffer list.

Comment: I think the `<c-^>/<c-6>` trick is what I was looking for, and I'll probably remap it too because on my azerty keyboard it's absolutely not convenient. Thank you for these additionnal informations!

Comment: You can also do `:tab help <topic>` to make it open in a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

The Vim 9.0 `tips.txt` help file contains a section on this topic. See:

```
:help help-curwin
```