# Vim: cursor manipulation in help file

Tags: vimscript, autocmd

So I want to be able to automatically open help files in a new tab.

I saw [a question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3716/open-help-windows-in-new-buffer-instead-of-split-windows) on this SE that pretty much solved my problem.

I wanted to make just one change: center the screen.

"That will be easy," I thought....

```
"Only apply to .txt files...
augroup HelpInTabs
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufEnter  *.txt   call HelpInNewTab()
augroup END

let g:help_in_tabs = 1

"Only apply to help files...
function! HelpInNewTab ()
    if &buftype == 'help' && g:help_in_tabs
        "Convert the help window to a tab...
        execute "normal \<C-W>T"
        " THIS IS MY CHANGE:
        execute "normal zz"
    endif
endfunction
```

quite unexpectedly, there is no difference. ☁️

Comment: Do you have `zz` mapped to anything? Just in case, use `normal! zz` (I'm pretty sure you don't need the `execute` statement either. Also, you can just do `:tab help <topic>` to open a help page in a new tab.

Comment: Yes I use nescroll.nvim which maps zz. But I just tried it with normal! zz and also before with gg to no avail 

Comment: I prefer to open help in a split window, and possibly on the right (with wide screens there is enough room to keep help and text open at the same time).
I created a mapping:

`map <Leader>ve :vertical botright help<CR>`

Comment: I tried your code. Manually calling `HelpInNewTab()` gives the desired result. Even running `:doautocmd` works. But when firing automatically, there is no change, as you mentioned. In addition, I found that after switching to another tab and back, the screen is centered! I think this might be a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code, and indeed, `zz` has no effect. In fact, reducing the function to contain only `normal zz` did not center the help window automatically.

A workaround is to use a `timer`. That is, in your function, replace `execute "normal zz"` with

```
call timer_start(0, {-> feedkeys("zz")})
```

Let's break it down:

- `timer_start` creates a timer, that executes a function after some time specified by the first argument, which is...
- `0`, that is, execute the following function immediately
- `{-> feedkeys("zz")}`: a lambda expression (anonymous function), which behaves as though the user entered `zz`.

Basically, after waiting (albeit for 0 seconds), press `zz`.

For more, see

- `:h timer`,
- `:h expr-lambda`,
- `:h feedkeys()`.